# Retaining Textbox Value

Tags: c#, sql, database, textbox

I'm trying to update a person's details in the database. Since I'm using textboxes, how would I keep the original value if the textbox is empty?

I'm trying to write it in a short way rather than having a tonne of IF statements.

The code I've written will work but not the way I want, any suggestions on what I could do?

Code (C#):

```
 foreach (Control c in pnlUpdate.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox questionTextBox = c as TextBox;
                if (questionTextBox.Text == "")
                {
                    questionTextBox.Text = pat[0].Forename;
                    questionTextBox.Text = pat[0].Surname;
                    questionTextBox.Text = pat[0].Street;
                    questionTextBox.Text = pat[0].Town;
                    questionTextBox.Text = pat[0].City;
                    questionTextBox.Text = pat[0].DOB.ToString();
                    questionTextBox.Text = pat[0].House_number;
                    questionTextBox.Text = pat[0].Mobile;
                }
            }
        }
```

Pat = database object

Comment: What Backend are U using?

Comment: What's pat[0]? It's not very clear where the database interaction is happening.

Comment: Its the database table & C#

Comment: May I suggest you use *more than one* textbox to show the values from `pat`:)

Comment: why can't you keep a required field validator for that particular text box so that it doesn't allow null values and you can update only if there is value in the text box

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to update a person's details in the database. Since I'm using textboxes, how would I keep the original value if the textbox is empty?

Use Server Validation. To make sure that user has entered values for all controls you need to use RequiredFieldValidator. Go through below link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hbw267h(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Something like below will provide you the help

```
pat[0].Name = TextBox.Text == "" ? pat[0].Name : TextBox.Text
```